# How to create more than one cluster in minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, kubernetes-security

I need to create additional cluster in minikube. I searched for a while I haven't got any resource on this.How to create a cluster in minikube?

Answer (score 13):

Create first cluster named `cluster-1`:

```
minikube start -p cluster-1
```

Create second cluster named `cluster-2`:

```
minikube start -p cluster-2
```

Switch between the clusters:

```
# switch to cluster-1
minikube profile cluster-1

# switch to cluster-2
minikube profile cluster-2
```

Comment: First I though `-p` is not documented, but it is. See `minikube options`