# How to use two minikube profile in parallel?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to create two profiles and deploy pods to each minikube profile in parallel instead of deploying pods to one profile and then switching to another profile and then deploying pods again. I am not seeing anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
minikube start -p p1
minikube start -p p2
kubectl apply -f <app.yml> --context p1
kubectl apply -f <app.yml> --context p2
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be there is no feasibility or possibility to use the two profiles simultaneously.
You can track the latest updates on this concern in this [GitLink](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/15548).
Refer to this [doc](https://ervikrant06.github.io/kubernetes/Kuberenetes-Minikube-profile/) and  for  How to run multiple minikubes on a single machine and [minikube Profile](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/profile/), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586788/how-to-create-more-than-one-cluster-in-minikube) for commands for switching the profiles.